# Is there an explanation for the disproportionally small head of the Great Sphinx of Giza?

Tags: ancient-egypt

While I don't subscribe to the [Orion correlation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orion_correlation_theory) or the related [water erosion theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphinx_water_erosion_hypothesis), the head of the Great Sphinx of Giza is disproportionally small compared to its body. The fringe theories mentioned explain that by having the Sphinx be a statue of a lion, much older, which had its head reshaped to resemble that of a Pharaoh much later.

**Is there a widely accepted explanation for its disproportionally small head?**

Or is the head just not *that* small?

Comment: How big _is_ the head of a sphinx compared to its body? Whose standard of proportion should we be using?

Comment: Of course, if you are building something only with rock (and not a very hard one because you have to carve in), how big the chunk at the top is is limited by how much weight the chunks under it can support. Add to it a reasonable security margin because the engineers do not want to become cocodrile fodder, should the head collapse. Or maybe the slaves'trade union complained and got a better deal...

Comment: It is very hard for me to judge how well the proportions are respected in the Great Sphinx of Giza because I've never observed with enough attention a real, living Sphinx.

Comment: @Evargalo I think the Berlin Zoo has one. But seriously, compared with other sphinxes (both Egyptian and other, such as Greek), the head seems small.

Comment: It's supposed to be a lion body with a human head, and I'm sure most human's heads would look small on a lion's body. Maybe the Egyptians were going for realism.

Comment: The thing that I've always wondered about is why the front feet are so big. It appears to be for effect when looking straight at it. Also, how is the body explained to be so much more eroded than the head?